# How can I make a function in Excel that counts down 7 days and then resets

Tags: excel

I need a fuction in Excel that counts down 7 full days and then after 7 days have passed it should reset back and count down again 7 full days.

Answer (score 0):

With a start date in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=$A$1-MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,8)
```

[image]

*(the countdown pattern is shown in column **C**)*